# How to send image file through multipartentitybuilder?

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

I am trying to send image file through `multipartentitybuilder`, but it is not working.

Can anyone help me where I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url); 
//request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic"); // if we need authorization

String fileName="C:\\Desert.jpg";
File file = new File(fileName);

FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(new File(fileName), ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY);
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
//builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
builder.addTextBody("X-FPA-Meta-File-Name", "test.jpg");
builder.addTextBody("Username","a");
builder.addTextBody("Password","a");

builder.addBinaryBody("part1", file, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, "java.jpg");

final HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
request.setEntity(entity);

HttpResponse response = null;
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

try {
    response =  httpclient.execute(request);        
} catch (SocketException se) {
    System.out.println(se);
    throw se;
}
```